# Using an array count in `if` statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to count the amount of arrays in an array that was converted from a hash. I want to use this to specify what arrays I want, then convert them back into hashes.

Here is my controller:

```
entry_by_start_date = Entry.where("approve_disapprove = ?", '1').group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date}
entry_by_end_date = Entry.where("approve_disapprove = ?", '1').group_by {|i| i.leave_end.to_date}
@entry_by_date = entry_by_start_date.merge(entry_by_end_date) {|key, oldval, newval| oldval}
@ad = @entry_by_date.to_a
ff = @ad.count
if ff == 5
  @t = Labor.all.group_by {|i| i.transaction_date.to_date}
  v = @t.to_a
  q = v[-1], v[0], v[1]
  pp = Hash[q.map {|key, value| [key, value]}]
  @s = pp
  puts true
else
  puts false
end
```

The `if` doesn't work. It always returns the `else` `false`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind the count wasn't 5 which is why it kept returning false haha! Thanks anyways!